# ASP.NET MVC: Route any error requests to my custom page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC, I need to route any error requests to my custom page, can I use this way?

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{*pathInfo}", 
new { controller = "Home", action = "NotFound" } 
);
```

And, are there any better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2007/11/22/asp-net-mvc-framework-handling-exception-by-using-an-attribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In the global.asax:

```
  public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
  {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute() { View = "YourView" });
  }
```

Comment: Of course this only works when one uses MVC3+. No global filters in version 1 and 2...